# Can we remove the Create a new site button on Web8 UI

Tags: web8

Can we remove the Create a new site button option on Web8 UI

When user login with Editor they see a button called Create a New Site Under Sites Section, the button is disabled , but if we want to completely remove the button from displaying from UI. Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuratio option available for you to remove the button. You could consider building a UI extension to remove the button, but it is not advisable to use UI extensions to change defauilt behaviour as it can lead to unexpected circumstances.

My main question on these type of requests are always, why exactly would you want to do this? Do you have a good explanation as to why you would want to take away functionality that is offered to the user by the product. I've often notices that we try to "help" the customer by removing functionality from them that they might not know how to use correctly, while in the end a bit of education would really help them in using it properly and enhance their experience.

Answer (score 2):

Disable that group's permission to launch new sites and the editors should not see the option anymore.

See the docs [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-F3D5039B-0FBE-48E0-9652-0C58CB58F852) where it explains what you need to do to *enable* it, and do the reverse :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nuno.

I tested the "create a new site" button is disabled for non-admin users and user only content entry privileges.

[image]

Comment: Was this supposed to be a comment to my answer?

Answer (score -2):

site button enable only administrator user privileges. I do not think it is not enable for other users.

Comment: It is enabled for everyone